# How to execute code on parent component when I load child route?

Tags: angular

I try to implement a sidebar menu that'll change item according to child route.
ie: the basic sidebar menu contents are alerts and gestion. When I click on alerts for example I redirect to url /alerte and I want to change the content of the sidebar menu. I've put my code in ngInit() function. But there is any reload of the page so the code can't execute (If I'm right). when I reload my page the sidebar content change with what I want. I'm asking myself if it's the right way to do it ?? or should I try to pass data from child to parent ??

When I initialize the parent component I do some check on the url to pass content to an array that's used in the parent template. If I'm on '/alvin/home' I pass the defaults items and when it's different I want to request API to get data to field the sidebar.

My sidebar component

```js
export class SideNavComponent implements OnInit {

 menus : string[]=[];
 href: string = '';

  constructor(private router: Router, public sideNavService: SideNavService, public plateformeService: PlateformeService) { }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.href = this.router.url;
    console.log('essai: '+this.href);
    if (this.href == '/alvin/home'){
          this.menus.push('alerte');
          this.menus.push('gestion');
    }
    if (this.href == '/alvin/alerte'){
      this.plateformeService.getAll().subscribe(menus => {
        for (let m of menus){
                          this.menus.push(m.nom);
        };
      });
    }

  }
}
```

I want to change items when I load a child route. Thank you for help

Comment: add event listener on navigation and render menu items depending on navigation state

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it works

Comment: You can also observe the ActivatedRoute Observable, which changes with each route change